# problem in connecting c# console program to oracle database defined on database server has a firewall

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, firewall, oracle.manageddataaccess

This is the error message generated when program try yo open a connection
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string'

ExtendedSocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. 149.193.5.103:1432

review connection string no problem with it and i am already use it to connect to database using plsqldeveloper oracledevleoper and other c# web programs but i do not use with it Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Comment: Oracle is very sensitive to version of Oracle and version of Driver.  I do not know in this case if it is a version issue.  What is the difference between the connection string in working and non working apps?  Is the port number 1432 correct?  Oracle default port number is 1521.  Oracle may be using TLS.  See : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/security/transport-layer-security-tls-protocol-overview.html#GUID-69ECD56C-3B20-47F4-AEF0-A06EFA13A61D